# Java goldbach conjecture using sieve of eratosthenes

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to create a program where you input a number and it tells you the pair(s) of prime numbers that add up to that number.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Goldbach
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please input an integer to find two prime numbers whose sum add up to it.");
    int input = scan.nextInt();
    if(input < 4)
    {
      System.out.println("Number must be greater than or equal to 4");
    }
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    int[] primes = generatePrimes(input);    
    findPairs(input, primes);
    long endTime = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println("\n This program took: " + (endTime-startTime) + " nanoseconds or " + ((endTime-startTime)*1e-9) + " seconds.");
  }

  private static int[] generatePrimes(int max)
  {
    boolean[] isComposite = new boolean[max + 1];
    for (int i = 2; i * i <= max; i++)
    {
      if (!isComposite [i])
      {
        for (int j = i; i * j <= max; j++)
        {
          isComposite [i*j] = true;
        }
      }
    }
    int numPrimes = 0;
    for (int i = 2; i <= max; i++)
    {
      if (!isComposite [i]) numPrimes++;
    }
    int [] primes = new int [numPrimes];
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 2; i <= max; i++)
    {
      if (!isComposite [i]) primes [index++] = i;
    }
    return primes; 
  }

  private static void findPairs(int input, int[] primes)
  { 
    String primepairs = "";
    for(int i = 1; i < primes.length; i++)
    {
      for(int j = 1; j < primes.length -1; j++)
      {
        if((j > i) && ((j+i) == input))
        {
          primepairs = (primepairs == null ? "" : primepairs + "\n") + j + " + " + i + " = " + input;
        }
      }
    }
    System.out.println("\n" + primepairs);
  }
}
```

I have tried debugging however I haven't been successful. Could you help me debug this? Thanks for pointing me in the right direction

Final Code:

```
 /* Title: Goldbach Conjecture
 * Author: Harris R
 */

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Goldbach
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please input an integer to find two prime numbers whose sum add up to it.");
    int input = scan.nextInt();
    if(input < 4)
    {
      System.out.println("Number must be greater than or equal to 4");
      return;
    }
    if(input%2 > 0)
    {
      System.out.println("Number must be even.");
      return;
    }
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    int[] primes = generatePrimes(input);    
    findPairs(input, primes);
    long endTime = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println("\n This program took: " + (endTime-startTime) + " nanoseconds or " + ((endTime-startTime)*1e-9) + " seconds.");
  }

  private static int[] generatePrimes(int max)
  {
    boolean[] isComposite = new boolean[max + 1];
    for (int i = 2; i * i <= max; i++)
    {
      if (!isComposite [i])
      {
        for (int j = i; i * j <= max; j++)
        {
          isComposite [i*j] = true;
        }
      }
    }
    int numPrimes = 0;
    for (int i = 2; i <= max; i++)
    {
      if (!isComposite [i]) numPrimes++;
    }
    int [] primes = new int [numPrimes];
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 2; i <= max; i++)
    {
      if (!isComposite [i]) primes [index++] = i;
    }
    return primes; 
  }

  private static void findPairs(int input, int[] primes)
  { 
    String primepairs = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < primes.length; i++)
    {
      for(int j = i; j < primes.length; j++)
        {
            int p = primes[i];
            int q = primes[j];
            if(p+q == input)
            {
                primepairs += "\n" + q + " + " + p + " = " + input;
            }
        }
      System.out.println("Program Completion: " + (((double)i/primes.length)*100) + "%");
    }
    System.out.println(primepairs);
  }
}
```

Comment: It is traditional on Stack Overflow to have a question, in the question.

Comment: Sorry about that, I fixed it now but it's a bit late.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `generatePrimes` method seems ok.

Your `findPairs` method doesn't make a lot of sense as you are adding array indices `i` and `j` rather than the primes `primes[i]` and `primes[j]` at those indices.

Here is a corrected version

```
private static void findPairs(int input, int[] primes)
{
    String primepairs = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < primes.length; i++)
    {
        for(int j = i; j < primes.length; j++)
        {
            int p = primes[i];
            int q = primes[j];
            if(p+q == input)
            {
                primepairs += "\n" + q + " + " + p + " = " + input;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("\n" + primepairs);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked. I can't believe I made such a simple error.

One quick question though. Wouldn't it be more efficient to also include an if statement to check the array index as you don't need to recheck numbers that you already checked? Also couldn't you use primes.length -1 as the last one would have already been checked?

Comment: @HarrisR I did something similar to that by making `j` start from `i`. I think you're right: length - 1 would be ok for the smaller index.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Everything is working how I wanted except 1 thing. When I enter 10, it spits out "5+5=10" but it won't include "7+3=10" do you know why this is?

Comment: My code prints both (I just checked). If you use `primes.length - 1` for the `j` array you won't get `7` because it's the last prime in the array.

Comment: Thanks, got it all working now. If I could vote up your answers, I would.

Comment: I came across another weird phenomenon, when I enter 4 no output is created. Looking at my code I can't see why this occurs, as 2 is created in generatePrimes.

http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=3TaZM74u

Comment: It's because your code says `for(int i = 1; i < primes.length; i++)`. It should say `for (int i = 0`... `2` is the first prime in the array, and array indices start at `0`, not `1`. By the way, you can accept answers, even with a small reputation :) http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Thanks for all the help